# .NET Entity Framework auto generated SQL query - what is THEN '0X1X' ELSE '0X2X' END part?

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, ado.net

Whenever I look at the SQL code behind my Entity-Famework query, this is in the 1st line. I know how IF ELSE in T-SQL works, but what are the 0X1X and 0X2X and simmilar values for?

They do vary from query to query, but are always written in simmilar form.

Example:

```
SELECT
CASE WHEN ([UnionAll1].[C2] = 1) THEN '0X0X' ELSE '0X1X' END AS [C1],
[UnionAll1].[Id] AS [C2],
[Extent3].[Draft] AS [Draft],
[Extent3].[Type] AS [Type],
[Extent3].[VipStatus] AS [VipStatus],
[Extent3].[OIB] AS [OIB],
[Extent3].[PartnerName] AS [PartnerName],
[Extent3].[Status] AS [Status],
[Extent3].[CreditWorthiness] AS [CreditWorthiness],
[Extent3].[IsBlacklisted] AS [IsBlacklisted],
[Extent3].[IsResident] AS [IsResident],
[Extent3].[IsTaxPayer] AS [IsTaxPayer],
[Extent3].[IsNewsletterSubscriber] AS [IsNewsletterSubscriber],
[Extent3].[Kind] AS [Kind],
[Extent3].[RegionalAffiliation] AS [RegionalAffiliation],
CASE WHEN ([UnionAll1].[C2] = 1) THEN [UnionAll1].[C1] END AS [C3],
CASE WHEN ([UnionAll1].[C2] = 1) THEN CAST(NULL AS varchar(1)) ELSE [UnionAll1].[FirstName] END AS [C4],
CASE WHEN ([UnionAll1].[C2] = 1) THEN CAST(NULL AS varchar(1)) ELSE [UnionAll1].[LastName] END AS [C5],
CASE WHEN ([UnionAll1].[C2] = 1) THEN CAST(NULL AS datetime2) ELSE [UnionAll1].[DateOfBirth] END AS [C6],
CASE WHEN ([UnionAll1].[C2] = 1) THEN CAST(NULL AS int) ELSE [UnionAll1].[Gender] END AS [C7],
CASE WHEN ([UnionAll1].[C2] = 1) THEN CAST(NULL AS bit) ELSE [UnionAll1].[IsEmployed] END AS [C8],
CASE WHEN ([UnionAll1].[C2] = 1) THEN CAST(NULL AS varchar(1)) ELSE [UnionAll1].[Profession] END AS [C9],
CASE WHEN ([UnionAll1].[C2] = 1) THEN CAST(NULL AS varchar(1)) ELSE [UnionAll1].[HzzoMbo] END AS [C10]
FROM   (SELECT
    [Extent1].[Id] AS [Id],
    CAST(NULL AS varchar(1)) AS [C1],
    [Extent1].[FirstName] AS [FirstName],
    [Extent1].[LastName] AS [LastName],
    [Extent1].[DateOfBirth] AS [DateOfBirth],
    [Extent1].[Gender] AS [Gender],
    [Extent1].[IsEmployed] AS [IsEmployed],
    [Extent1].[Profession] AS [Profession],
    [Extent1].[HzzoMbo] AS [HzzoMbo],
    cast(0 as bit) AS [C2]
    FROM [dbo].[Person] AS [Extent1]
UNION ALL
    SELECT
    [Extent2].[Id] AS [Id],
    [Extent2].[Name] AS [Name],
    CAST(NULL AS varchar(1)) AS [C1],
    CAST(NULL AS varchar(1)) AS [C2],
    CAST(NULL AS datetime2) AS [C3],
    CAST(NULL AS int) AS [C4],
    CAST(NULL AS bit) AS [C5],
    CAST(NULL AS varchar(1)) AS [C6],
    CAST(NULL AS varchar(1)) AS [C7],
    cast(1 as bit) AS [C8]
    FROM [dbo].[Company] AS [Extent2]) AS [UnionAll1]
INNER JOIN [dbo].[Partners] AS [Extent3] ON [UnionAll1].[Id] = [Extent3].
[Id]
```

To produce more examples, simply put a breakpoint in controller and when it stops, mouse over on `context.someTableModel` until the query appears :)

It's more of satisfying curiosity question then code problem.
I have searched both here and in MSDNA for this, but couldn't find an exact explanation. I assume that is how SQL server keeps flags or something on the result of the query?

Comment: I believe that it will be more clear if you show the full query. I am pretty sure that it is technical column that would be used for UNION/SORT or other kind of internal operations.

Comment: They seem to be values added by EF as type markers. See [this link](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/42ccba5c-8004-4f23-9b78-7143527089e5/code-onlyugly-sql?forum=adodotnetentityframework) and [this other link](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/6df9599f-c165-4a0e-9b92-ca58a8fc3816/is-there-a-way-to-know-the-sql-generated-by-entity-framework-in-debugging-time?forum=adodotnetentityframework).

Comment: @marc_s So, now it's Entity-Famework :D Fixed it, ty for edit I am terribly dyslexic sometimes :(